# Facebook php sdk post image to wall (source path)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

what path is actually in source?:

```
$photo = $facebook->api("/me/photos", "POST", array(
    source => "@" . "YOUR_IMAGE_PATH",
    message => "YOUR_MESSAGE"
));
```

Image path from the server (should I upload image first to my server?) or $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']?

I just get CurlExceptionfailed creating formpost data

Where can I get image path?
Thanks

Comment: Your “or” question is moot, because having the data in $_FILES would mean it has been uploaded via HTTP to the server already. And did you call `Facebook::setFileUploadSupport` first?

Comment: I have set $config['fileUpload'] = true; for Facebook sdk, I just dont know wich path of image should be use.

Comment: How bout – the _correct_ one …? It’s your server, so you should know best, hm?